# list box alignment problem

Tags: c++, linux, qt

[image: interface]

[image]

hello every one i am facing a problem . i have a list view in which i am displaying the items retrieved from the file my file is my file each line of file contain tab separated entries (sample file attached) but when i display it in my list view, item didnt appear aligned.here is the code

```
void list_load(QStandardItem * root)
  {
  FILE * f;
  f=fopen("/home/cv/mod2an3run/output/mod3run/sample.txt","r");

  if(f==NULL)
    {
    printf("not open");
    root->appendRow(new QStandardItem("ash"));
    }

  QString buffer ="";
  char ch = ' ';

  while (ch!=EOF)
    {
    ch = fgetc(f);
    if(ch!='\n')
      {
      buffer = buffer+ch;
      }

    if(ch=='\n')
      {
      QString status= range(prob);
      buffer = buffer +"\t"+ status ;
      root->appendRow(new QStandardItem(buffer));
      buffer="";
      }
    } //while end

  fclose(f);
  }// func end
```

i have attached my interface and sample file out put kindly help me to align my list box items

Answer (score 3):

It's *probably* to do with the tabs in the input stream in conjunction with differing field sizes.

If you examine the two lines where the second column is shifted further left than the others, you'll see they're relatively short IP addresses. While your editor may be using a tabstop of 8 and fixed-width fonts, your listbox is different, *especially* since the `.` separator is a thinner character in the proportional font it's using.

Ditto for the lines where the third column is left shifted (other than those two already mentioned).

You may be able to solve it simply by choosing a fixed width font for your listbox. In my opinion, your *best* bet will be to separate each line into columns. You can do this because the first two columns have no spaces in them (being IP addresses).

Then, using a fixed width font, display each column padded out to a certain size with spaces. This should fix any issues with both the font widths *and* the tabstops.

For example, your first line may be:

```
118.107.140.11<tab>66.20.151.93<tab>Wed May 18 blah blah blah
```

Separate that into three different data items (split at the tabs or whatever other delimiter is in use), then pad the two IP addresses data item out to fifteen character each (largest IPv4 is `255.255.255.255`).

You would also have to pad out the date field to ensure your `NON SUSPICIOUS` column would line up.

Then output them with a couple of spaces between them:

```
118.107.140.11   66.20.151.93     Wed May 18 blah blah blah  NON SUSPICIOUS
50.56.2.200      118.107.128.235  Wed May 18 yada yada yada  SUSPICIOUS
```

Comment: thanks alot sir but sir but how to pad and also i am retreving the item from the list box will the padding effect the retrieved item  because i have to do some work on that item

Comment: You pad by appending spaces until it's the right length, or you can use something like `stringstream` to make it easier. If you want to bring stuff _back_ from the list and use the original form, you'll have to extract the whole fifteen characters then strip off trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a QTableView with 4 columns instead of a QListview. And you should look up the following classes and functions in the excellent Qt help system:

- QTextStream
- QTextStream::readline
- QString
- QStringList
- QString::split
- Q_FOREACH